# Specification in `theorem` environment also bold

Tags: environments, amsmath, theorems, bold

I'm using the following packages/options in my article:

```
\documentclass[b4paper,12pt]{article}   
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amssymb}                
\usepackage{amsmath}                
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{hyperref}               
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{color}              

\newtheoremstyle{break}
   {\topsep}{\topsep}%
   {\itshape}{}%
   {\bfseries}{}%
   {\newline}{}% 
\theoremstyle{break}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

\begin{definition}[Test]
This is a test definition
\end{definition}
```

I would like to have the name (here 'Test') not only in parentheses but also boldface. How can I achieve that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your [`amsthm`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm) specification for the `break` theorem style should look like this:

```
\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{break}
   {\topsep}{\topsep}%
   {\itshape}{}%
   {\bfseries}{}%
   {\newline}
   {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {\bfseries(#3)}}}% 
\makeatother
```

The header is managed using the ninth argument. I've just copied it from the [`amsmath` source](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/required/amslatex/amscls/amsclass.dtx) and replaced the note font with `\bfseries`. If you leave it empty, it defaults to the `plain` theorem header style.

Here's your original MWE with the above modification:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}   
%\usepackage[english]{babel}
%\usepackage{amssymb}                
%\usepackage{amsmath}                
%\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsthm
%\usepackage{hyperref}               
%\usepackage{graphicx}
%\usepackage{color}              

\makeatletter
\newtheoremstyle{break}
   {\topsep}{\topsep}%
   {\itshape}{}%
   {\bfseries}{}%
   {\newline}
   {\thmname{#1}\thmnumber{\@ifnotempty{#1}{ }\@upn{#2}}%
    \thmnote{ {\bfseries(#3)}}}% 
\makeatother
\theoremstyle{break}

\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}%[section]
\newtheorem{lemma}[theorem]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{proposition}[theorem]{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}[theorem]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}[Test]
This is a test definition
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I was looking for. I couldn't figure it out by looking for it in the source code...thanks for the help!